# how to write 301 redirect code for woocommerce product

Tags: redirect

I need to 301 redirect in WooCommerce :

http://www.sitename/shop/product-category/sample-product/product-name

to

http://www.sitename/product/product-name

Comment: I think it's better to write with htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If you already created a new product you can write directly in your product template before get_header()

```
global $post;
if($post->ID===$your_old_product_ID){
  wp_redirect(site_url('/product/product-name/'),301);
}
```

But it will be better if you create some custom field in products to manage their redirects.

Comment: I think it's better to write with htaccess

Comment: Wordpress has a special function for redirect - wp_redirect(). Why do you think .htaccess is better?